# In django admin page, some table are not in the available permission list

Tags: django, permissions, admin

My super user can edit all tables and auth user/group correctly.
I would like to setup some less power user, who can only edit some tables.
but i found not all tables are listed in the available permission list.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually do a "python manage.py syncdb" fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you run sync_perms after adding permissions to these new tables?

Comment: what do you mean by sync_perms? manage.py doesn't have this command. it only has syncdb, which no help on my problem

Comment: Sorry, I meant syncdb. The only reason I can think of for not all tables being listed is that some apps may not be in your INSTALLED_APPS file.